# Use Cloud Functions for Firebase HTTPS with GET Method

Tags: firebase, https, get, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Can someone tell me how to use firebase-functions.https.onRequest() for GET method? 
So the problem is I want to have get url like : /getData/{type}/{id}

I have tried

```
exports.getProduct = functions.https.onRequest("/getProduct/{type}/{id}",(request, response) =>{});
```

But its still not working, what I can do with that snippet code is https://firebase-url/getProduct which I cant put some parameter.

Answer (score 8):

The `https` function trigger setup does not have any path matching baked in, however you can achieve this by using an Express app (as an example) for your HTTPS function:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.get('/:type/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.params);
});

exports.getProduct = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

In general you can also simply inspect `req.url` of the request, it is a path relative to the function name:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.getProduct = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.send(req.url);
});
```

In the above function, a `GET` to `/getProduct/foo/bar` would have a `req.url` equal to `/foo/bar`.

Comment: Apologies to hijack this post. I noticed you work at firebase and was wondering if you could help me out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600367/firebase-cloud-function-error-could-not-handle-the-request