# How to use Firebase Firestore in a HTTP Trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

How do I save data to Firestore in Firebase Functions?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.saveContact = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    admin.firestore().collection("contact").add({
        name: request.name;
    }).then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });

    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

With this code I'm getting this error

> Error: could not handle the request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Functions for Firebase: 'Error: could not handle the request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600367/cloud-functions-for-firebase-error-could-not-handle-the-request)

Comment: Are you also initializing the Admin SDK using `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`? There will be a description of the error in the Firebase console under Functions which will better explain the issue.

Comment: Thank you Jen, that's what was missing.